# How to sort out display on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian, hdmi, display

I am running Raspbian on my raspberry pi, and have it plugged in to a vga display via a converter. The display is way to zoomed in, and I wondered how to fix that.

When I run /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -s I see:
state 0x12001a [HDMI CEA (1) RGB full 4:31, 640x480 @ 60Hz, progressive

When I run /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -m CEA I see:
Group CEA has 1 modes:
  (prefer) mode 1: 640x480 @60Hz 4:3, clock:25MHz progressive

Thank you!

Comment: Define "via a converter".

Comment: "Via a converter" means I have connected it to a VGA display through a HDMI to VGA converter box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read up on the /boot/config.txt file

http://elinux.org/RPiconfig

Open it to edit

> sudo nano /boot/config.txt

These are probably the options you are looking for, uncomment to use them:

> framebuffer_width=1280
>
> framebuffer_height=720

From the looks of things, there might be a lot of fiddling with the options that you have to do. For example try this:

> hdmi_group=2